# Hovering on a search result tag should give the option for adding to the search

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, search

When searching I don't always think to add relevant tags, or I discover a new tag that might help narrow down my search.

To make the process smoother, could a button to 'add to search' be added to the tag popover?

[image: popover card for a tag on the search results page. A button labeled '+ Add to search' has been added]

This would rerun the search with the given tag, changing the URL params from `?q=beast+sense+familiar` to `?q=beast+sense+familiar+%5Bdnd-5e%5D`.

The only concern I'd have (with my web developer hat on) is that currently the search returns a document rather than JSON data, meaning that you'd need a full page reload each time.

This ***old*** request is asking [Add/remove tags from a search via right click or hover popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89184/add-remove-tags-from-a-search-via-right-click-or-hover-popup) but is about a different part of the UI.

Comment: "*meaning that you'd need a full page reload each time.*" eh, it's not different to what you need to do right now, anyway. If you want to refine your search, you'd add another tag to the search bar and then search again. Which leads to a reload of the page. Making part of that process smoother is still an improvement.

Comment: Too bad that the hovercard is pretty inaccessible on mobile (which probably needs a shortcut more). On iOS you can long tap on a tag as a substitute for hovering at least.